# Best way to share artifacts in the same organization but in a different project in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I have a org in azure devops which has multiple projects. There are scenarios where we would like to share artifacts from one project scoped feed to another project. There are possible 2 ways to share those

1. Add them as a upstream sources to consuming project's project scoped feed
2. Have multiple project scoped feed refereed in the configuration file in the consuming application.

Which is the best solution and why ?

Comment: Hi friend. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer which will also help others in the community. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

According to the document about [Best practices for using Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/best-practices?view=azure-devops):If you want to use packages from multiple feeds, use upstream sources to bring packages from multiple feeds together into a single feed.

Here are the benefits of upstream sources:

Upstream sources enable you to manage all of your product's dependencies in a single feed. We recommend publishing all of the packages for a given product to that product's feed, and managing its dependencies from remote feeds in the same feed, via upstream sources. This setup has a few benefits:

- Simplicity: your NuGet.config, .npmrc, or settings.xml contains
  exactly one feed (your feed).
- Determinism: your feed resolves package requests in order, so
  rebuilding the same codebase at the same commit or changeset uses the
  same set of packages.
- Provenance: your feed knows the provenance of packages it saved via
  upstream sources, so you can verify that you're using the original
  package, not a custom, or malicious copy published to your feed.
- Peace of mind: packages used via upstream sources are guaranteed to
  be saved in the feed on first use. If the upstream source is
  disabled/removed or the remote feed goes down or deletes a package
  you depend on, you can continue to develop and build.